# Ubuntu 13.10 can not show all resolutions of my Monitor

Tags: display, resolution

I have a problem about resolutions. I just open my computer and when it is opening Ubuntu gave and error message something like `"errors have been founded .. for manual recovery s to skip continue to wait ..."` something like this.

so I just press I to ignore that and it opened successfully. but I realized that the resolution has an error. when I open `system settings`> `displays` it told me that the monitor is unknown. And the highest resolution that I can see is `1024X768`. 
I checked for broken packages, enter a code to terminal like

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

And tried more stuffs to fix it but I just could not. here is my latest screen shot which explains everything, I hope.

So, summary is Ubuntu 13.10 can not recognize what monitor I am using. so it can't show every resolutions.

How to fix it, please ?

[image]

Comment: Please tell me what computer you have, at least your graphics card.

Comment: It says ATI RV370. 

but it fixed already and I really don't know how, it is like, it's like it has fixed by itself. like how the problem appear by unknown reasons, once I opened my PC and I saw that Saucy can recognize my monitor without any problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing arandr

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Then open arandr to and select your resolution.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem (a VGA switch that does not pass EDID signals along). The resolutions `arandr` shows are limited to 1024x768 and lower.

Comment: It's a reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/449867